# `signal` function on CentOS: unexpected behavior

Tags: c++, multithreading, sockets, signals, signal-processing

I need to disable `SIGPIPE` on CentOS application, because this signal crashes my application when it works with unstable Internet connection.
I use following code in `main` function:

```
signal(SIGPIPE, SIG_IGN);
```

However, program still crashes with `SIGPIPE`. What is the reason? Have I to call this function on each thread, or it is enough to call in `main` function, and program will ignore `SIGPIPE` globally? And if it is not required to be called on each thread, why `SIGPIPE` still crashes program if it is supposed to ignore the signal?

Comment: IN multithreading application you should not use _signal_ but _sigaction_. read [here](http://www.linuxprogrammingblog.com/all-about-linux-signals?page=11) for more details

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here it is a code sample that let you set up your own signal handler on linux, catch SIGPIPE and do something with that.

```
#include <signal.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <cerrno>
#include <system_error>
#include <iostream>

static sigset_t theMask;
static int count = 0;

static void
signalWrapper(
    int         theSignalNumber,
    siginfo_t*  theSignalDescription,
    void*       theUserContext)
{
  // Do something here as reaction to you SIGPIPE
  // This is better way to react on such things

  std::cout << "Got signal " << theSignalNumber << std::endl;

  // Reinstall handler
  struct ::sigaction sa;
  sa.sa_sigaction = &signalWrapper;
  sa.sa_mask = theMask;
  sa.sa_flags = SA_SIGINFO;

  try
  {
    if (::sigaction(theSignalNumber, &sa, NULL) == -1)
      throw std::error_code(errno, std::system_category());
  }
  catch (const std::error_code& ec)
  {
    std::cerr << ec << std::endl;
  }

  count++;
}

void
setupSignalHandlers()
{
  struct ::sigaction sa;

  // Prepare mask
  sigemptyset(&theMask);
  sigaddset(&theMask, SIGPIPE);
  // Add some more if you need it to process

  sa.sa_mask      = theMask;
  sa.sa_flags     = SA_SIGINFO;
  sa.sa_sigaction = &signalWrapper;

  // Perform setup
  try
  {
    if (::sigaction(SIGPIPE, &sa, NULL) == -1)
      throw std::error_code(errno, std::system_category());
  }
  catch (const std::error_code& ec)
  {
    std::cerr << ec << std::endl;
  }
}

int
main()
{
  std::cout << "Set handler!" << std::endl;
  setupSignalHandlers();

  std::cout << "Emit 5 SIGPIPE signals" << std::endl;
  while (count < 5)
  {
    kill(getpid(), SIGPIPE);
    usleep(100);
  }

  return 0;
}
```

and output:

```
Set handler!
Emit 5 SIGPIPE signals
Got signal 13
Got signal 13
Got signal 13
Got signal 13
Got signal 13
```

I provide signal handler since it is more correct to process signal that breaks your application than ignore it. Perhaps you need to reestablish connection or do some other stuff.

Answer (score 1):

According to the man page for Signal(2), "The Effects of signal() in a multithreaded process are unspecified." You might try making sure to call signal() in the main thread before creating any other threads, but it's not guaranteed to work.

In any case signal() is deprecated, so I would suggest switching to sigaction(). I use it in multithreaded applications all the time without any problems.